# How can I get the number of messages sent by a user in a discord server without discord.py?

Tags: python, http, discord, discord.py

Using discord's search function manually, you can enter something like `from:user#3456` and it will show you how many messages they've sent on the server (at least, messages you have access to).

I've been told there is no way to get this information through discord.py, but is there really no way to get that data at all? Would I have to resort to a web scraping tool?

To be clear, I have looked at [history()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=history#discord.Member.history) already. What I'm looking for is a way to access the search function that Discord already has.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually possible using [`discord.TextChannel.history`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=history#discord.TextChannel.history). Here is an example:

```
userMessages = []

userID = 1234567890 # Change this to the ID of the user you are looking messages for
channelID = 1234567890 # Change this to the channel ID of the messages you want to check for

channel = client.get_channel(channelID)
user = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id== userID, channel.guild.members)

async for message in channel.history():
    if message.author == user:
        userMessages.append(message.content)

print(len(userMessages)) # Outputs total user messages
```

Make sure you replace `1234567890` with the corresponding IDs.

I've added an array which also shows all the user messages, if you prefer you can remove that and have it increment a counter instead.

Comment: I tried this but it just prints out 0 since the print statement executes before the async loop finishes

Comment: Did you change the IDs `1234567890` to the correct IDs?

Comment: I did, and actually using your exact method of appending to a list and taking the length of the list did get a non-zero answer, I expect because its slower than incrementing a counter which is what I did originally. However, the number printed is still way too low. In my case, discord search says 2,353 messages, this code says 47

Comment: 47 Is probably is the amount of messages sent by the user and 2353 is the total number of messages in the channel???

Comment: No, like I said, the user sent over 2353 messages in the channel. from:user in:thischannel, search says 2353

Comment: I'm not sure then, that means the bot only found 47 of them :/

Comment: History only pulls the [first 100 messages by default](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=history#discord.TextChannel.history), and a user only posted 47 of them.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this in a kind of hacky way by searching with a `from:username` query in the Discord app, looking at the http request with Chrome DevTools, and finally recreating the request with the python module `requests`.

In Discord in a browser, you can open DevTools with the f12 key.

In DevTools, navigate to the `Network` tab.

I'd suggest to fill in the search query (but don't hit enter), *then* open devtools, then hit enter on the search. Otherwise there will be a lot of http requests that pop up as you type.

Then, you find the request with a name that looks like "search?author_id=1234567890". If you click on that request, you can see the details necessary to recreate it.

The key parts of the http request you need to use are the `Request Headers` section and the `Request URL` under the `General` section, all in the `Headers` tab that pops up when you first click on the request, and the `Response` tab to see what your response will look like.

[image: discord http request in chrome devtools]

The `accept-encoding` attribute of the Request Headers includes `br`, but this seems to jumble the result. Keeping it to just `gzip, deflate` works for me.

Using the `requests` python module this should be pretty easy to set up. So long as `br` is not listed in `accepted-encoding`, you should be able to use the `json()` method of `requests`, and for the particular problem of finding the total messages sent by the user (whose id you must insert into the request URL), it's simply accessible with `my_request_variable.json()['total_results']`.

The main thing to watch out for is the `authorization` request header. This is unique to the user (you, unless you do all this from someone else's account) and you can't substitute in a discord bot's token, unfortunately.